# integration of xgboost with h2o functionalities

Tags: xgboost, h2o

I see that recently xgboost has been integrated within the H2O ecosystem. Nevertheless lack of documentation appears in the H2O. In particular I wonder whether It is possible to run a grid search on all xgboost params using the h2o.grid.

Comment: Please look in the docs before posting here.

Comment: Hi Erin, I did of course, but unfortunately it is not explicitely declared if grid search is enabled for xgboost.

Comment: Giorgio, sorry if that was not clear in the docs.  XGBoost is listed in the Grid Search page (along with a list of it's grid-able parameters), which means that you can use a grid search on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The H2O-XGBoost documentation is in the Algorithms section of the H2O User Guide, [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html).

The hyperparameters for Grid Search are also listed with all the other algorithms in the Grid Search section, [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/grid-search.html#xgboost-hyperparameters).

Comment: I tried to run Grid Search for XGBoostEstimator in python but it does not seem to work even though the same code works for GBM and RFs. `h2o.exceptions.H2OResponseError: Server error water.exceptions.H2ONotFoundArgumentException:
  Error: POST /99/Grid/None not found
  Request: POST /99/Grid/None
    data: {u'response_column': 'xxx', 'nfolds': '2', u'hyper_parameters': "{'ntrees': [50, 100], 'max_depth': [3, 10]}", u'training_frame': 'py_yyy'}`

Comment: @user90772 Thanks for the report.  This is a known bug, documented here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4704?filter=21100

Comment: Thank you, is this a bug only for Python or it is not supported in any language?

Comment: @user90772 Yes, it is working in R.  I made a demo here: https://gist.github.com/ledell/71e0b8861d4fa35b59dde2af282815a5

Comment: @user90772 XGBoost grid search in Python is now fixed on master: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4704  To get the changes, git clone the h2o-3 repo and build from master; or wait a day for it to be in the nightly release: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/latest.html

Comment: Hi @Erin LeDell , I checked H2OXGBoostEstimator.available() and it outputs true, but I still get an error that xgboost is not registered when I use it in grid. any idea why?

Comment: @EmmaNej Can you post a reproducible example as a new post?  Please include what OS you're using and which version of H2O.  Thanks!

Comment: @ErinLeDell I have posted the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104483/xgboost-in-pysparkling-water-throws-an-error-xgboost-is-not-available-on-all-no